# reconstruct signal from fft

Tags: c++, fft

Im reconstructing signal from amplitude, frequency and phase obtained fft. After I do fft, I picked some of its frequencies and reconstructed time line signal from those fft data. I know IFFT is for this but, I dont want to use IFFT. 
Reconstruction seems fine but theres some time lag between two signals. This image shows this problem. Black one is the original signal and red one is that reconstructed.
[image]

If I know correctly, amplitude of frequency bin t is `sqrt(real[t]*real[t] + imag[t]*imag[t]` and phase is `atan2(imag[t], real[t])`.
So, I used formula `amplitude * cos(2*π*x / frequency + phase)` for a frequency bin. And I summed those regenerated waves. As far as I know, this should generate intact signal fits to original signal. But it ends up always with some time lag from original signal.

Yeah, I think its about phase but thats so simple to calculate and its working correctly. If it has error, reconstructed signal would not fit to its original signal in shape.

This is the code to generate cosine wave. I generated cosine wave from sin(x + π/2).

```
std::vector<short> encodeSineWavePCM(
    const double frequency,
    const double amplitude,
    const double offSetPhase)
{
    const double pi = 3.1415926535897932384626;
    const int N = 44100; // 1 sec length wave
    std::vector<short> s(N);
    const double wavelength = 1.0 * N / frequency;
    const double unitlength = 2 * pi / wavelength;
    for (int i = 0; i<N; i ++) {
        double val = sin(offSetPhase + i * unitlength);
        val *= amplitude;
        s[i] = (short)val;
    }

    return s;
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: There's no need to re-post your question, you should edit your original question to preserve the discussion.

Comment: "I know IFFT is for this" - and it's the _only_ transform that gives you back the original. But why the irrational dislike for the IFFT?

Comment: for test purpose. This is sound signal and I'm trying to make a original sound back from major frequencies of the original signal. Does it must make the same sound if I play each frequency at the same time?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand that last sentence. "Frequency" is associated with a sine wave, which is _not_ localized in time, so you can't really talk about "the same time".

Comment: yea, u r right. I was just trying to simulate "simultaneous" sound play back environment. make each frequency into sound signal and play them at once. thats what i meant.

Answer (score 1):

Quite normal. You're doing a frame-by-frame transform. That means the FFT frame is produced *after* one time frame. When transforming back, you have the inverse effect: your time frame starts *after* the FFT frame has been decoded.

Comment: That seems correct. reconstructed signal plot fits after its original signal. But this is getting more confusing. :(

Comment: Could you plz explain why this is happening? As far as I understand, Fourier Series just input signal into its frequency domain. How time frame can be involved?

Comment: Don't confuse things. Fourier Series is a related thing, not an FFT. The Fourier Series is a mathematical construct for a periodic signal defined at any moment. You very much have a discrete signa, and the FFT works on that. That said, how big is your input sound (in samples), and how many samples do you pass to the FFT? They're probably not the same.